# I'm not sure what this code is trying to do

Tags: scheme

`(define changeit (lambda (x) (* x x)))
(define changeall 
  (lambda (x)
    (if (null? x)
        '()
        (cons (changeit (car x)) (changeall (cdr x))))))
(changeit 8)
(changeit 9)
(changeall '(2 14 10 8))`

I'm not really sure what `changeall` is doing, can anyone help explain it?

EDIT: Here is the rest of the code

Comment: I recommend that you run it in your REPL. We can't know because we don't know what `changei` does.

Comment: It's a `map` that `square`s all the elements of its input list. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Although Oscar Lopez's comment sums up what is going on, this answer is a bit more detailed. `changeit` is simply the `x^2` function. `changeall` is a function of one argument. If that argument is the empty list (`(null? x)`), the function returns the empty list. Otherwise, `changeall` calculates the square of the first element of its argument list (`(car x)`) and prepends it to the result of a call to `changeall` with the rest of its initial argument list (`(cdr x)`). This is a recursive function call. At some point, the argument list will be exhausted, that is, the argument will be the empty list, and `changeall` will return the empty list (the first case we considered). At this point, the recursion will stop.